# Comparing multidimensional arrays and add property to every child, even in child arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, vue.js

I am working on the permission part of my application. I am building actually a vue application that get's supplied by a Laravel back-end, made by someone else. Now I get a little bit stuck how to check if a permission is checked or not and is active under a role. A permission can belong to a role, So when making a role, I have to check which permissions belongs to the role.

So first I get all permissions I have in an array. This will be an array with 3 parent permissions, with its own children permissions, and so on, like 4 times deep.

The permissions

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Suppliers management module",
            "description": "This permission allows the user to access the underlying permissions",
            "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule",
            "guard_name": "web",
            "_lft": 1,
            "_rgt": 34,
            "parent_id": null,
            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Suppliers management module settings",
                    "description": "This permission allows the user to access the underlying permissions",
                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings",
                    "guard_name": "web",
                    "_lft": 2,
                    "_rgt": 33,
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "name": "Supplier types",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to access the underlying permissions",
                            "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.supplierTypes",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 3,
                            "_rgt": 12,
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": 4,
                                    "name": "Create supplier types",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to create supplier types",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.supplierTypes.create",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 4,
                                    "_rgt": 5,
                                    "parent_id": 3,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 5,
                                    "name": "Read supplier types",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to read supplier types",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.supplierTypes.read",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 6,
                                    "_rgt": 7,
                                    "parent_id": 3,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 6,
                                    "name": "Update supplier types",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to update supplier types",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.supplierTypes.update",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 8,
                                    "_rgt": 9,
                                    "parent_id": 3,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 7,
                                    "name": "Delete supplier types",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to delete supplier types",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.supplierTypes.delete",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 10,
                                    "_rgt": 11,
                                    "parent_id": 3,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 8,
                            "name": "Suppliers management module sections",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to access the underlying permissions",
                            "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.sections",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 13,
                            "_rgt": 22,
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": 9,
                                    "name": "Suppliers management module create sections",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to create suppliers management module sections",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.sections.create",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 14,
                                    "_rgt": 15,
                                    "parent_id": 8,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 10,
                                    "name": "Suppliers management module read sections",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to read suppliers management module sections",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.sections.read",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 16,
                                    "_rgt": 17,
                                    "parent_id": 8,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 11,
                                    "name": "Suppliers management module update sections",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to update suppliers management module sections",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.sections.update",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 18,
                                    "_rgt": 19,
                                    "parent_id": 8,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 12,
                                    "name": "Suppliers management module delete sections",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to delete suppliers management module sections",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.sections.delete",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 20,
                                    "_rgt": 21,
                                    "parent_id": 8,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 13,
                            "name": "Suppliers management module labels",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to access the underlying permissions",
                            "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.labels",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 23,
                            "_rgt": 32,
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:42",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": 14,
                                    "name": "Suppliers management module create labels",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to create suppliers management module labels",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.labels.create",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 24,
                                    "_rgt": 25,
                                    "parent_id": 13,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 15,
                                    "name": "Suppliers management module read labels",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to read suppliers management module labels",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.labels.read",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 26,
                                    "_rgt": 27,
                                    "parent_id": 13,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 16,
                                    "name": "Suppliers management module update labels",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to update suppliers management module labels",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.labels.update",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 28,
                                    "_rgt": 29,
                                    "parent_id": 13,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 17,
                                    "name": "Suppliers management module delete labels",
                                    "description": "This permission allows the user to delete suppliers management module labels",
                                    "translation_key": "suppliersManagementModule.settings.labels.delete",
                                    "guard_name": "web",
                                    "_lft": 30,
                                    "_rgt": 31,
                                    "parent_id": 13,
                                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "Relations module",
            "description": "This permission allows the user to access the underlying permissions",
            "translation_key": "relationsModule",
            "guard_name": "web",
            "_lft": 35,
            "_rgt": 46,
            "parent_id": null,
            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "name": "Relations",
                    "description": "This permission allows the user to access the underlying permissions",
                    "translation_key": "relationsModule.relations",
                    "guard_name": "web",
                    "_lft": 36,
                    "_rgt": 45,
                    "parent_id": 18,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 20,
                            "name": "Create relations",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to create relations",
                            "translation_key": "relationsModule.relations.create",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 37,
                            "_rgt": 38,
                            "parent_id": 19,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 21,
                            "name": "Read relations",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to read relations",
                            "translation_key": "relationsModule.relations.read",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 39,
                            "_rgt": 40,
                            "parent_id": 19,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 22,
                            "name": "Update relations",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to update relations",
                            "translation_key": "relationsModule.relations.update",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 41,
                            "_rgt": 42,
                            "parent_id": 19,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 23,
                            "name": "Delete relations",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to delete relations",
                            "translation_key": "relationsModule.relations.delete",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 43,
                            "_rgt": 44,
                            "parent_id": 19,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "Settings",
            "description": "This permission allows the user to access the underlying permissions",
            "translation_key": "settings",
            "guard_name": "web",
            "_lft": 47,
            "_rgt": 68,
            "parent_id": null,
            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 25,
                    "name": "Languages",
                    "description": "This permission allows the user to access the underlying permissions",
                    "translation_key": "settings.languages",
                    "guard_name": "web",
                    "_lft": 48,
                    "_rgt": 57,
                    "parent_id": 24,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 26,
                            "name": "Create languages",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to create languages",
                            "translation_key": "settings.languages.create",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 49,
                            "_rgt": 50,
                            "parent_id": 25,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 27,
                            "name": "Read languages",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to read languages",
                            "translation_key": "settings.languages.read",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 51,
                            "_rgt": 52,
                            "parent_id": 25,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 28,
                            "name": "Update languages",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to update languages",
                            "translation_key": "settings.languages.update",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 53,
                            "_rgt": 54,
                            "parent_id": 25,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 29,
                            "name": "Delete languages",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to delete languages",
                            "translation_key": "settings.languages.delete",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 55,
                            "_rgt": 56,
                            "parent_id": 25,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 30,
                    "name": "Roles",
                    "description": "This permission allows the user to access the underlying permissions",
                    "translation_key": "settings.roles",
                    "guard_name": "web",
                    "_lft": 58,
                    "_rgt": 67,
                    "parent_id": 24,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 31,
                            "name": "Create roles",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to create roles",
                            "translation_key": "settings.roles.create",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 59,
                            "_rgt": 60,
                            "parent_id": 30,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 32,
                            "name": "Read roles",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to read roles",
                            "translation_key": "settings.roles.read",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 61,
                            "_rgt": 62,
                            "parent_id": 30,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 33,
                            "name": "Update roles",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to update roles",
                            "translation_key": "settings.roles.update",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 63,
                            "_rgt": 64,
                            "parent_id": 30,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 34,
                            "name": "Delete roles",
                            "description": "This permission allows the user to delete roles",
                            "translation_key": "settings.roles.delete",
                            "guard_name": "web",
                            "_lft": 65,
                            "_rgt": 66,
                            "parent_id": 30,
                            "created_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "updated_at": "2018-06-14 15:58:43",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to retrieve a role, I will also get permissions belonging to that role. So now, I have to check which permissions are already included for the role and which one not, out of that list of all permissions.

What is the best way of comparing the two arrays? What I've tried so far:

```
// Set the array with permissions
this.permissions = response.data.data;

// Push all permissions in one array
this.permissions.forEach((element) => {
    this.AllPermissions.push(element);

    element.children.forEach((one) => {
        this.AllPermissions.push(one);

        one.children.forEach((two) => {
            this.AllPermissions.push(two);

            two.children.forEach((three) => {
                this.AllPermissions.push(three);
            });
        });
    });
});

// Push the id's of the permissions of a role to an array
this.role.permissions.forEach((element) => {
    this.permissionsNumbers.push(element.id);
});

// Check for each permission if a permission belongs to the role
this.AllPermissions.forEach((item) => {
    if (this.permissionsNumbers.includes(item.id)) {
        item.check = 1;
    } else {
        item.check = 0;
    }
});
```

But for some reason, this feels really weird. For instance, I do 4 `foreach` loops because there are around 4 children arrays, but what happens when I add another children array? Than I have to add manually another `foreach` loop. Also, Now I get the permissions belonging to a role as one big array. Instead I would like to get that as an array with children arrays etc. How can I manage that with comparing instead of a big list with items?

Thanks anyway for helping out in advance, please feel free to ask questions when things are not fully clear.

Comment: so if a role has a parent permission all children should also be included, correct?

Comment: Well that will be ideal, That's already been set up in the back-end, that instead of the whole list with permissions belonging to a role, I get the array with parent  + children and so on. My main question is, how do I compare that array, with the array of general permissions So I can check which permissions belonging to a role are active or not.

Comment: @bambam Updated the question. Btw, you can ask it nicely. Don't use sarcasm, it offends people. The image was there to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

I put this together to illustrate recursively calling an array, also remember that objects are always passed by reference in javascript, so you can just edit them as you iterate and use the original array. I don't know how your class is actually built, so this may take some adapting for it to work.

```
class permHelper{
    constructor(permissions, role){
        this.permissionsNumbers = [];
        this.role = role;
        this.role.permissions.forEach((element) => {
            this.permissionsNumbers.push(element.id);
        });
        this.AllPermissions = this.getPermissions(permissions);
    }

    getPermissions(perms, parentChecked){
        perms.forEach((perm) => {
            if(hasPerm){

                //parentChecked is sent in when the parent permission
                //was valid so we know all children are valid
                perm.check = 1;

            }else if(this.permissionsNumbers.includes(perm.id)){

                //If the parent wasn't valid, or this is the top level,
                //check agains the permissions on the role
                perm.check = 1;
            }else{

                //If the role doesn't have this permission  or one of its
                //ancestors permissions, this one isn't valid either
                perm.check = 0;
            }

            //If this permission has children, run them through also
            if(typeof perm.children != 'undefined') this.getPermissions(perm.children, perm.check);
        });

        //Return the altered array
        return perms;
    }

}
```

If you'd rather that AllPermissions was an array the only contained the valid permissions:

```
class permHelper{
    constructor(permissions, role){
        this.AllPermissions = [];
        this.permissionsNumbers = [];
        this.role = role;
        this.role.permissions.forEach((element) => {
            this.permissionsNumbers.push(element.id);
        });
        this.getPermissions(permissions);
    }

    getPermissions(perms){
        perms.forEach((perm) => {
            if(this.permissionsNumbers.includes(perm.id)){
                this.AllPermissions.push(perm);
            }else{
                //If the role doesn't have this permission this one isn't valid
                if(typeof perm.children != 'undefined') this.getPermissions(perm.children, perm.check);
            }
        });
    }

}
```